# ways to handle errors when debugging and database access is not possible

Tags: .net, database, error-handling

I'm going to apologize in advance as i know the topic of this question is a little vague.

my problem:

we are giving out software to clients who don't want us to have access to their database. so fundamentally if there is a problem, we cant request a database backup to reproduce the errors that are being thrown.

this is an age old problem, and one that puts developers in a tricky situation when trying to solve issues with the client. i'm just wondering if anyone has any design tips or has a link to a useful guide to help me with this. i've tried searching around but i haven't found anything useful on this matter.

Thanks, Alex :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I propose the following:

1. Try the **.Net Reflector** from redgate in case u are using .net 4 or later [.Net Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/our-company/about/news/dot-net-reflector).
   I haven't tried it personally but it says it could debug assemblies without having the source code.
2. The second option will be to use a log file: create a function to write in a text file, and in ur code wherever you want to check a value, add that function. You can pass that function a boolean parameter that u can read from the webconfig file.